# How to emulate HTTP response from requests_mock post method

Tags: python, json, http, rpc, http-status-codes

I'm trying to test how is @retry.retry decorator for my custom method works. For this I need to emulate the situation when response has HTTP statuses in ranges 2xx, 3xx, 4xx.
Right now I have an example with requests_mock:

```
def some_method(request, *_):
    ...
    return {'jsonrpc': '2.0', 'id': 1, 'result': True}

with requests_mock.Mocker() as mock:
    mock.post('mock://test', json=some_method)
    ...
    ...
    my_sender.send(...) # <- tinyrpc.RPCClient.get_proxy somewhere inside
```

What **some_method** should return to emulate 404 for example, if it's possible?

In general, the situation is as follows: **mocker** returns j**son rpc 2.0** now. I would like to test the case when **http status** has specific codes, for some of which I need to make a repeated request. How can I do this emulation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone interested, how to emulate this, this is very easy to do:

```
import requests
import requests_mock

session = requests.Session()

with requests_mock.Mocker() as adapter:
    adapter.post('mock://test.com/4', [
        {'text': '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": 1, "body": {"verdicts": [], "errors": {"some_service": "server_error"}}}', 'status_code': 500},
    ] * 3 + [
        {'text': '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": 1, "body": {"verdicts": []}}', 'status_code': 200},
    ])

    data = '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": 1, "body": {"text": "hi"}}'
    resp = session.post('mock://test.com/4', data=data)
    print(resp.status_code, resp.text)
    resp = session.post('mock://test.com/4', data=data)
    print(resp.status_code, resp.text)
    resp = session.post('mock://test.com/4', data=data)
    print(resp.status_code, resp.text)
    resp = session.post('mock://test.com/4', data=data)
    print(resp.status_code, resp.text)
    resp = session.post('mock://test.com/4', data=data)
    print(resp.status_code, resp.text)
    resp = session.post('mock://test.com/4', data=data)
    print(resp.status_code, resp.text)
    resp = session.post('mock://test.com/4', data=data)
    print(resp.status_code, resp.text)
```